# Reliable way of getting initial size of QWidget

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

I have a custom widget. It's purpose is to display an image (with possibility of scaling, rotation etc).

My goal is to calculate initial scale of the image so its size would match widget's size.

My first attempt was to do it in constructor, but it wasn't right place (as widgets are usually put into layouts after construction, so their size change later).

Another way, which partially works is to override `showEvent` or `resizeEvent` and put there initial scaling. It works partially, because it works fine on desktop but for some reason it doesn't on android device - `QWidget::size()` returns the same size as in constructor.

Apparently on android first show/resize events are called before final window rearrangement.

Is there a clean way to achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a QLabel, either instead-of or inside the widget (you can set its border to 0px) and use [setScaledContents](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop).

Comment: My widget has extra functionality for operating on the image by user and `QLabel` doesn't fulfill my all needs. Also I don't want the image to be scaled when widget changes its size later (by resizing whole window for example) which would happen with `QLabel`

Comment: I don't see how in resizeEvent it can show the wrong size and you posted no code so sorry about the question... did you call QWidget::size() before or after calling QWidget::resizeEvent(event)?

Comment: I never said `resizeEvent` gives me wrong results. I just need to know widget size after it was added to layout, and all widgets were placed to proper position and sizes. At such a point I want to get widget's size and scale image it holds appropriately.